# Картинка-ссылка не на ровне с текстом

Tags: html

У меня картинка-ссылка меняется на другую при наведении курсора и этот код отображает картинку:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/" class="rollover"></a>
```

А проблемка возникает такая: картинка появляется не на ровне с текстом

> ```
> <style>
>    a.rollover {
>     background: url(rlogo9.png);
>     display: block;
>     width: 105px;
>     height: 34px;
>    }
>    a.rollover:hover {
>     background: url(rlogo8.png);
>    }
>   </style>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какая картинка? Скиньте код css класса .rollover

Comment: не css
 <style>
   a.rollover {
    background: url(rlogo9.png); /* Путь к файлу с исходным рисунком  */
    display: block; /*  Рисунок как блочный элемент */
    width: 105px; /* Ширина рисунка */
    height: 34px; /*  Высота рисунка */
   }
   a.rollover:hover {
    background: url(rlogo8.png); /* Путь к файлу с заменяемым рисунком  */
   }
  </style>

Comment: попробуйте line-height: [высота рисунка]; vertical-align: middle;

Comment: вроде получилось но рисунок обрезан снизу вверх (видна только верхушка картинки-ссылки 1px) а так в одну строчку сделано